# How to spawn a mob with dyed wool head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can successfully summon a mob with equipment and a block head. However when I try to summon a mob with a dyed wool block head, using `wool:14`, it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to summon a mob with dyed wool block head?

Note: I'm running 1.8

Comment: Maybe provide more information. How exactly are you trying to summon this mob? What happens when you try? Does it do nothing? Does it spawn with the wrong head?

Comment: ok so when i do this i spawns with no item via red wool({id:wool14}]

Comment: and also if i take a way :14 it spawns with a white wool head and if i do it with any other block like "log" or "anvil" it works so i cant find the problem

Comment: and i used a command_block

Comment: @Peter, can you add the full command you are using, and perhaps a full command that does work? You can edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 2):

When summoning a mob with equipment, you don't combine the metadata into the id, there is a separate tag for metadata

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:wool,Damage:<Metadata>,Count:1}]}
```